# Ajax call fails with 405(method not allowed) after executing in servlet

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I have a strange situation. I'm making an GET ajax call to my web application and can see the code in the servlet execute with no error and exits out of the my doGet() method just fine. But the response I get on the browser shows 405 method not allowed error. This is strange. I tried switching to POST method type(though mine is a GET) and got the same error.

I see no errors in the log.

What could wrong in here?

-Srini.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which library you are using for AJAX. Try it from the command line with `wget` or `curl` to verify the web server is working and sending the correct values back. Also try a REST client like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/reviews?hl=en-US&utm_source=ARC to test with easier.